# How to find the output response of a second order system?

Tags: laplace-transform, control-theory

Consider a second order system with the following transfer function:

$$
G(s)=\frac{\omega_{n}^{2}}{s^{2}+2 \zeta \omega_{n} s+\omega_{n}^{2}}
$$

If the input is:

$$ \cos (\omega t) $$

how can I find the output response of the system?

Comment: What have you tried? What is the normal way to get from input + transfer to output?

Comment: I took Laplace Transform of cos(wt) and wrote Y(s) = swn²/(s²+w²)(s²+2Ewns+wn²). Then, I obtain partial fractions. However, I am not sure if this way is true.

Comment: Convert the input in Laplace domain and perform the multiplication then apply the inverse laplace transform